# How do I use a spark variable in an html helper?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, spark-view-engine

Can I use a spark variable inside an html helper?

Say we have

```
<var url="Url.Action(“get”)" />    
!{Html.Image("~/Content/up.png")}
```

Now if I need to use the `url` inside `Html.Image` as an attribute(part of the 2nd param) to get

```
<img src="~/Content/up.png" type="~/engine/get" />
```

how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Did you try `!{Html.Image("~/Content/up.png",url)}` ? As far as I remember, Spark will generate code `var url = Url.Action(“get”)`, so you can use this variable later.

Comment: you shud have put this as an answer :-)

Comment: I added answer. I had to check it first at home, because I wrote answer from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<var url='Url.Action("get")' />
```

is converted to

```
var url = Url.Action("get");
```

when interpreting view code, so you can use `url` as C# variable later:

```
!{Html.Image("~/Content/up.png",url)}
```